# all strings are printing on the console at the same time in assembly language 8086

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am having a problem with my assembly code I was making a linear search program and in that program i have initializes two strings; the string when user is asked to input a number and other when there is a positive result but the problem is that when i run my program, all strings are printing at the same time on the console.

note: there are some other errors also but please ignore them at this time.

```
include irvine32.inc
.data

searchArr   WORD    1, 4, 7, 14, 299, 156, 3, 63, 29, 300, 20
user_input word ?
search_str byte "enter the number you want to search",0ah,0dh

yes_str byte "the number is in given array",0ah,0dh
.code
main proc

mov edx,offset search_str
call writestring

mov edx,0

; asking the number from user
call readint
mov user_input , ax

mov eax,0

;seacrhing the array
mov ecx, (lengthof searchArr)
mov esi,0
search:
mov bx,searchArr[esi * type searchArr]
cmp bx,user_input
je yes 

inc esi

loop search

yes:
mov edx,0
mov edx,offset yes_str
call writestring
exit


main endp
end main
```

Comment: You need to zero terminate your strings. Also please fix the formatting in the question.

Comment: thanks man it now working great